# Форма обратной связи

Tags: php, html, форма

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы скрипт обратной связи работал? При условии, что форма будет в файле .html (например: index.html), а php-код, например, в файле mail.php.

```
<?php
    $msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы

    if($_POST['btn_submit']){
        $errors = array(); // контейнер для ошибок
        // проверяем корректность полей
        if($_POST['user_name'] == "")    $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваше имя' не заполнено!";
        if($_POST['user_email'] == "")   $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваш e-mail' не заполнено!";
        if($_POST['text_comment'] == "") $errors[] = "Поле 'Текст сообщения' не заполнено!";

        // если форма без ошибок
        if(empty($errors)){     
            // собираем данные из формы
            $message  = "Имя пользователя: " . $_POST['user_name'] . "<br/>";
            $message .= "E-mail пользователя: " . $_POST['user_email'] . "<br/>";
            $message .= "Текст письма: " . $_POST['text_comment'];      
            send_mail($message); // отправим письмо
            // выведем сообщение об успехе
            $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;'>Сообщение успешно отправлено!</span>";
        }else{
            // если были ошибки, то выводим их
            $msg_box = "";
            foreach($errors as $one_error){
                $msg_box .= "<span style='color: red;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
            }
        }
    }

    // функция отправки письма
    function send_mail($message){
        // почта, на которую придет письмо
        $mail_to = "my@mail.ru"; 
        // тема письма
        $subject = "Письмо с обратной связи";

        // заголовок письма
        $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Тестовое письмо <no-reply@test.com>\r\n"; // от кого письмо

        // отправляем письмо 
        mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Обратная связь</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <?= $msg_box; // вывод сообщений ?>
    <br/>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="frm_feedback">
        <label>Ваше имя:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?=($_POST['user_name']) ? $_POST['user_name'] : ""; // сохраняем то, что вводили?>" /><br/>

        <label>Ваш e-mail:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?=($_POST['user_email']) ? $_POST['user_email'] : ""; // сохраняем то, что вводили?>" /><br/>

        <label>Текст сообщения:</label><br/>
        <textarea name="text_comment"><?=($_POST['text_comment']) ? $_POST['text_comment'] : ""; // сохраняем то, что вводили?></textarea>

        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="btn_submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сейчас после нажатия на "Отправить" сообщение отправляется, но перебрасывает на http://сайт.ру/mail.php
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать что-бы после нажатия на "Отправить" выводилось сообщение: "Сообщение успешно отправлено!"?

Comment: Навороченный какой код! Ужос )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно вместо `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` прописать `action="mail.php"` в html-файле. Этим атрибутом (action) Вы указываете, куда будет отправлять данные форма. О формах можно почитать, например, [тут](http://www.php5.ru/study/forms).

Comment: а как быть с этим:
<?= $msg_box; // вывод сообщений ?>
<?=($_POST['text_comment']) ? $_POST['text_comment'] : ""; // сохраняем то, что вводили?>